# Why is preformatted text extending outside its container?

Tags: html

I have been tiring to put some text into border that I did.

```css
div {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  width: 200px;
  border: 15px solid crimson;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <pre>
    Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.
     </div>
            </pre>
```

Now I have a lot of text that i want to put inside the border. I'm using pre tag and it looks like this:

[image]

I'm trying to understand how to put the text inside the border, but everything that I have tried doesn't work. What can I do  to fix it?

Comment: Why do you want to use <pre> when you don't want the text be printed "preformatted" as written in the HTML file?

Answer (score 0):

Use `white-space: pre-wrap`.

```
div {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  width: 600px;
  border: 15px solid crimson;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
}
pre {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Comment: You'd need to set that on the `pre` rather than the `div` for it to work.